# Using CIM Maplex to include feature weights and never remove unplaced labels

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, labeling, cartographic-information-model

I'm using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.
I've been trying to add feature weights and to include unplaced labels to a feature class, yet my understanding of the CIM engine seems to be lacking. My code below doesn't seem to change anything. I know it it's missing some commands, I'm not sure what!

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
m = aprx.listMaps()[0]

lbl = m.listLayers(featureclass)[0]
l_cim = lbl.getDefinition('V2')
lc = l_cim.labelClasses[0]

lc.maplexLabelPlacementProperties.MaplexLabelFeatureType = "Point"
lc.maplexLabelPlacementProperties.enablefeatureWeight = True
lc.maplexLabelPlacementProperties.featureWeight = 200
```

Answer (score 2):

If the code sample you have provided is truly what you have written then you are missing the "write your changes back" step. Look at the example 1 sample code in the help file on [CIM](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/python-cim-access.htm) and you will see that the updates are written back with the setDefinition() method on the layer.

Comment: It's only a small sample and I realize I should have inserted more! I setDefinition() back on the layer. thank you for taking the time. I could add more if you're interested!